# How to select unique values?

Tags: mysql

I am trying to get this query to only display 1 result (not LIMIT) in this example:

```
SELECT company_id  FROM `location` WHERE `state` = 'XX'
```

It results are similar to this:

`16 9 9 9 9 30 30 30 45 50 50 50 50 57 7 79 80 80 80 80 120 120 120 120 120 128 131 120 265 265`

I am aiming for these results:

`16 9 30 45 50 57 7 79 80 120 128 131 120 265`

Comment: Note: you only need to escape fieldnames with backticks if they're reserved words.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add [`DISTINCT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/distinct-optimization.html) keyword before you column name

```
SELECT DISTINCT company_id FROM `location` WHERE `state` = 'XX'
```

The `DISTINCT` keyword in a `SELECT` statement removes duplicates returned by a query.

Answer (score 1):

Use `DISTINCT` keyword

```
SELECT DISTINCT company_id  FROM `location` WHERE `state` = 'XX'
```

It will give the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use `DISTINCT` when you want to retrieve distinct result set.....

```
SELECT DISTINCT company_id  FROM `location` WHERE `state` = 'XX'
```

You can use `Group By` as an alternative to DISTINCT in following way:

```
 SELECT company_id  FROM `location` WHERE `state` = 'XX' GROUP BY company_id
```

The `DISTINCT` and `GROUP BY` generates same execution plan as performance wise though I strongly recommend you to use `DISTINCT` in your scenario......